# PHP read JSON file From URL (I have a problem with this url)

Tags: php, json, curl, web-scraping, php-curl

I'm trying this.

```
php



    $urlx = "https://www.tmdn.org/tmview/api/trademark/detail/AR500000003159511";
    echo $urlx."<hr>";

    $lurl = getTMview($urlx);


function getTMview($url)    {
        
        $agent= "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0";

        try {
                $request_headers = [

                    'Content-Type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                    'Accept:    text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',

                ];
                
                $strCookie = 'PHPSESSID=' . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] . '; path=/';
               
                $curl = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath('COOKIE_FILE'));
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $strCookie);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT, 2 );
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE, false );
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, true);        
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS , 20);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLPROTO_HTTPS, true);

                $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
                $redirectedUrl = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

                if ($curl_response === false) {
                    throw new Exception(curl_error($curl), curl_errno($curl));
                }else {
                    $curl_response;
                }
                
                curl_close($curl);


                $fileJSON = $curl_response;

                echo "<pre>"; print_r($fileJSON);
                

        }catch(Exception $e) {

            trigger_error(sprintf('Curl falló con error: #%d: %s',$e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()),E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    }

?>
```

==========

But I can't get the json response, but if I copy and paste the url in the browser if it shows it. What I get in **response** is this but no error.

======

https://www.tmdn.org/tmview/api/trademark/detail/AR500000003159511

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
P3P: CP="{}"
Set-Cookie: TSc52fbf36029=0877a508f8ab28002302a94e31ca1ca3f9f80e8d60adfbeae9bc3ab0119554a8c2d27857b7fa39b02e1dc40e4243b162; Max-Age=30;Path=/;samesite=none;Secure
P3P: CP="{}"
Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 5430
P3P: CP="{}"
Set-Cookie: TSf8346f47027=0877a508f8ab2000a016ba36910d303990b09e456f92087e394a1bbfc51e3a3ed5983a3e8a799e5b080d3caf0b113000af09061e611dcfc0fa67e9c30833e3320f96cd04d86058a6dea70d934ae9a9ef600b4f75275fbd81322ffbf1a139e9e6;Path=/;samesite=none;Secure

=======

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Sure that is your correct code? Your function requires _two_ parameters, you only pass one

Comment: You are right it is only 1 parameter, but if you try it that is not the error. Maybe I already modified it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using the function in a matter like return $fileJSON;

Here is an example for your code this works.

Edited with fixed code:

```
<?php

$urlx = "https://www.tmdn.org/tmview/api/trademark/detail/AR500000003159511"; 
echo $urlx."<hr>";


$lurl = getTMview($urlx);
echo '<pre>';

print_r($lurl);

function getTMview($url) {

    $agent= "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0";

    try {
            $request_headers = [

                'Content-Type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                'Accept:    text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',

            ];

            $strCookie = 'PHPSESSID=' . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] . '; path=/';

            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath('COOKIE_FILE'));
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $strCookie);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT, 2 );
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE, false );
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS , 20);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLPROTO_HTTPS, true);

            $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
            $redirectedUrl = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

            if ($curl_response === false) {
                throw new Exception(curl_error($curl), curl_errno($curl));
            }else {
                $curl_response;
            }

            curl_close($curl);


            $fileJSON = $curl_response;

            return $fileJSON;


    }catch(Exception $e) {

        trigger_error(sprintf('Curl falló con error: #%d: %s',$e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()),E_USER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

This will work.

the response:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
P3P: CP="{}"
Set-Cookie: TSc52fbf36029=0877a508f8ab280078d2853fe8d32985ee08650c11af3bbfb3bba3ae155a7c0b39268e44ca72a94a8d245a5c624d55ac; Max-Age=30;Path=/;samesite=none;Secure
P3P: CP="{}"
Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 4932
P3P: CP="{}"
Set-Cookie: TSf8346f47027=0877a508f8ab2000748180282f1c9f77debce30924021930fe906c1adcd681bcc3f706103710149008c46db52d11300009e3f82113518c847fe985ab6fa69f57beaf40508ecd1e9a33309c342cc372e62d7ff80bdde40d7042a7f91391975530;Path=/;samesite=none;Secure

Comment: Maybe when I put the code I edited the function but the problem still persists.

function getTMview ($ url) { code }